# Adding condition in checkbox in html form to go to another question if they choose "Other"

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a condition whereas if they choose *Other*, they will be redirected to another question, 'Please specify, what brings you to San Francisco?' Otherwise if they check the other boxes it will go to this question, 'Do you currently rent an apartment, home, or room?'

HTML:

```
<div class="tab">
    <label for="brings"><h2>What brings you to San Francisco?:</h2></label><br>
    <label for="brings"><h2>Choose as many as you like:</h2></label>
    <br><br>
    <div id="radiocb" onclick="cbclick(event)"></div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /><h3> I am moving to work in San Francisco</h3></label><br><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /><h3> I am moving to study in San Francisco</h3></label> 
 <br><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /><h3> I am currently working in San Francisco</h3> </label><br><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /><h3> I am currently studying in San Francisco</h3></label><br><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /><h3> I am moving to live in the city, but I work/study 
  remotely</h3></label><br><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /><h3> I am moving here just to move! I need a new change of scenery</h3></label><br><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" /><h3> Other</h3></label>
    </select><br>     
    </div>  
    <div class="tab">        
    <label for="brings"><h2><p>Please specify, what brings you to San Francisco?:</p></h2> 
    </label><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br>
    <input type="text" id="brings" name="brings" value=""><br>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">        
    <label for="rent"><h2>Do you currently rent an apartment, home, or room?:</h2></label><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br>   
    <select id="rent">
    <option value="yes"><h3>Yes</h3></option>
    <option value="no"><h3>No</h3></option><br>
    </select><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want them to pick more than one? Seems like you should be using a radio button.

Answer (score 0):

You can define function call for that specific checkbox & do the redirection,
Below is code for your reference:

```js
function gotoNextQuestion()(obj) {
  if($(obj).is(":checked")){
    //redirect wherever
  }
  }
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" /><h3> I am moving to work in San Francisco</h3></label><br><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" /><h3> I am moving to study in San Francisco</h3></label> 
<label><input type="checkbox" onclick="gotoNextQuestion()"/><h3> Other</h3></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to go through checkbox and an if-statement to handle the *other* element.

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

for (let checkbox of checkboxes) {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      if (e.target.id === 'other') {
        window.location.href = '#other';
      } else {
        window.location.href = '#rent';
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 1500px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <h2>What brings you to San Francisco?:</h2>
  <h2>Choose as many as you like:</h2>
  <br><br>
  <div id="radiocb" onclick="cbclick(event)"></div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" />
    <h3> I am moving to work in San Francisco</h3>
  </label><br><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" />
    <h3> I am moving to study in San Francisco</h3>
  </label>
  <br><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" />
    <h3> I am currently working in San Francisco</h3>
  </label><br><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" />
    <h3> I am currently studying in San Francisco</h3>
  </label><br><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" />
    <h3> I am moving to live in the city, but I work/study
      remotely</h3>
  </label><br><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" />
    <h3> I am moving here just to move! I need a new change of scenery</h3>
  </label><br><br>
  <label><input id="other" type="checkbox" />
    <h3> Other</h3>
  </label>
  <br>
</div>
<div class="tab">
  <label for="brings">
    <h2>
      <p>Please specify, what brings you to San Francisco?:</p>
    </h2>
  </label><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="brings" name="brings" value=""><br>
</div>
<div class="tab">
  <label for="rent">
    <h2 id="rent">Do you currently rent an apartment, home, or room?:</h2>
  </label><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br>
  <select id="rent">
    <option value="yes">
      <h3>Yes</h3>
    </option>
    <option value="no">
      <h3>No</h3>
    </option><br>
  </select><br>
</div>
```

However, your HTML code is not valid. I haven't changed it for you, since this is not the scope of your question. Please use https://validator.w3.org/ to validate your code.

Comment: Which one I should change?

Comment: On the validation link that I have shared, you will get all the details. Just copy your code into _Validate by Direct Input_. Your code will still work, since modern browsers will correct them for you, but it's just to follow the best-practice.

Comment: The one you created is not working in my HTML form. The question is still going to "Please specify, what brings you to San Francisco?:" regardless of which checkbox they choose

Comment: This is what I understood from your question: If the checkbox _Other_ is checked, jump to _Please specify, what brings you to San Francisco?_. If any other checkbox is checked, jump to _Do you currently rent an apartment, home, or room?_.

Comment: That is correct

Comment: You have multiple errors in your HTML code. You are using a form into another form, setting the same ID multiple times etc. The JS code that I have posted works, but as I have mentioned, you should validate your HTML to see what you are doing wrong. Or if it helps you, see https://jsfiddle.net/gm2arjw3/. For instance, on line 143 you see an error.